# Can wp-config move cause dashboard not to load?

Tags: wp-config

BACKGROUND: About a week ago, I moved the wp-config.php file for a particular website into the root level of the server space, as allowed by WordPress. Everything seemed to work just fine.

PROBLEM: Today, I received an email from my client that she cannot access the dashboard. I checked and verified that going to the /wp-admin address causes the site to roll over to /not-found.

QUESTION: Have you seen this behavior? and, if so, what was the problem?

Note: this is a client who jumps to incorrect conclusions on a regular basis. But I have not seen this behavior before either.

Comment: when moving it back, does it fix the problem?  Did you move any other files?

Comment: You can get not-found error then re-update the permalinks. I think it's work but i am not sure just try it.

Comment: As per my knowledge wp-config.php is used for database connection In case you are not getting any error related to database it is fine.In that case you may please deactivate all plugins in your wordpress site or you can change permalinks from PHPMyAdmin if you are an experienced WordPress developer.

Comment: this sounds like some "security" plugin is in work, or there is some server misconfiguration